# C# radio button array, how to find selected

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following c# code that will create a radio button array.
How could I check which button was selected without going through each button individually?

Thanks.

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string[] stringArray = new string[3];

            stringArray[0] = "Yes";
            stringArray[1] = "No";
            stringArray[2] = "Maybe";

            System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[] radioButtons = new System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton[3];

            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
                radioButtons[i].Text = stringArray[i];
                radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
                this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RadioButton selected = radioButtons.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Just after creation all your radiobuttons will be unchecked, that's why I use `FirstOrDefault` instead of `First`. So, you should check if `selected` is not `null`.

UPDATE: If you want to do something each time when selected radiobutton changes (e.g. update some label with radiobutton text) then looping all radiobuttons is not best solution. You can subscribe all radiobuttons to same `CheckedChanged` event handler. In your loop add

```
radioButtons[i].CheckedChanged += RadioButton_CheckedChanged;
```

And handler is

```
private void RadioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radiobutton = (RadioButton)sender;
    if (radiobutton.Checked)
    {
        // some logic here
        label.Text = radiobutton.Text;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Linq query above is a shortcut for

```
RadioButton selected = null;

foreach(var r in radioButtons)
{
    if (r.Checked)
    {
        selected = r;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not understand. What is the difference ?? He asked for not iterating through all elements.

Comment: @Shaharyar I think OP didn't want to check each radioubutton individually. I.e. `if (radioButtons[0].Checked)`

Comment: I meant he asked for not checking all elements. I think creating `checked` event was better way to find which element has been checked.

Comment: @Shaharyar it depends. If you don't want to execute some logic when checked radiobutton changes, but you only want to get which one checked when you press OK button, then this is more simple, than subscribing to event and storing state somewhere

Comment: @Matthijs you can check `sender` of event. But still you need store that radiobutton somewhere to use it later

Comment: Yes ! by casting `sender` you can get checked element, and we have to store it somewhere to get at the end. I think it would be better if you include both solutions in your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry for being vague, I wanted to use a loop to check for which radiobutton is selected.

Comment: @user1763812 LINQ internally uses loop, but its much more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can store the index in the any property which you are not using. ie. `Tag`

```
radioButtons[i].Tag = i
```

and you can handle the `CheckedChanged` event of that element

```
AddHandler radioButtons[i].CheckedChange, AddressOf Item_CheckedChange
```

Now, you can write code to retrieve the selected index from Tag property.

```
Dim iSelectedIndex As Integer = -1
Private Sub Item_CheckedChange(...)
    Dim Item As RadioButton = DirectCast(sender, RadioButton)
    If Item.Checked Then
        'Here you will get the selected radio button from Item object
        iSelectedIndex = CInt(Item.Tag)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `radio button checked` event. First register event for all radio buttons:

```
//Modifying for loop
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton();
    radioButtons[i].Text = stringArray[i];
    radioButtons[i].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
    radioButtons[i].CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged; //added
    this.Controls.Add(radioButtons[i]);
}
```

Create new event:

```
RadioButton checkedButton;
void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton tempRdBtn = sender as RadioButton;
    if (tempRdBtn.Checked)
        checkedButton = tempRdBtn;
}
```

At the end you can check `checkedButton` for selected item. If its `null`, it means no item has been selected.